# "ows_LinkTitle" returns "undefined" for a folder created using CSOM in SP2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, csom

I have created a folder in a SP2010 list using CSOM. When I try to fetch if the folder exists in list, it returns "Undefined" to the SPService that I run.

For all folders created using GUI the name of folder is returned.
Also, I have tried setting up the value manually while creating the folder using `this.oListItem["ows_Title"]="My Folder";` yet folder does not seem to get this property.

Code for folder creation-

```
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();  
    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("List");  
    itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
    itemCreateInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);  
    itemCreateInfo.set_leafName("My Folder");
    var name=itemCreateInfo.get_leafName();
    alert(name);
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    this.oListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(this.oListItem); 
    this.oListItem["ows_LinkTitle"]="My Folder";
    this.oListItem["ows_Title"]="My Folder";
    alert(this.oListItem["ows_LinkTitle"]);
    alert(this.oListItem["ows_Title"]);
    this.oListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(this.oListItem);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(  
        Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),  
        Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler) 
     );  
     function successHandler() {  
        alert("Folder Created"); 
    }  

    function errorHandler() {  
        alert("Folder Creation Errored"); 
    }
```

Comment: Do not use the prefix "ows_"

Comment: @jpussacq
It doesnt work changing it, if i check the name using SP service below it still gives me "Undefined", find the code in comment below

Comment: Sorry, I did not read "SPService"

Comment: Kind of a work around but i found that if i check folder name using "ows_FileRefName" in SP Service i will get the result as "12;#My Folder" where 12 is ID of folder. So i can store this in a var and get folder name and compare. This property is set for all folders created using GUI or the above script. However the script does not create the proeprty ows_Title or ows_LinkTitle.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();  
oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("List");  
itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
itemCreateInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);  
itemCreateInfo.set_leafName("My Folder");
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
this.oListItem["Title"]="My Folder";
this.oListItem.update(); 
clientContext.load(this.oListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(  
    Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),  
    Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler) 
 );  
 function successHandler() {  
    alert("Folder Created"); 
}  

function errorHandler() {  
    alert("Folder Creation Errored"); 
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work i have tried this as well already

Comment: Find my code to find folders in list-
    function FolderCheck()
 {
 var arrFolder=[];
 alert("Into Sp Service");
 $().SPServices({
   operation:  "GetListItems",
   listName: "List",
   async: false,
   completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
   $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
    var folderName=$(this).attr("ows_Title");
    alert(folderName);
    });
    }
    });
 }
Also note if i remover "ows_Title" with "Title" in Service then it will give me undefined for all folders